# Song lyric accuracy/ type of usage

Tags: word-usage, american-english

There are lots of questions on this forum concerning song lyrics, but mine is related to English also.

1980's song China in your Hand has the line- *It was a theme she had on a scheme he had*

Question: can you have a theme on a scheme or  is this just word-play?

Does the clause have parallelism or is it just rhyming?

Answer (score 1):

There is no parallelism here. Parallelism is when parts of a phrase are omitted to avoid a repeat

> You can eat chips, or drink milk.  (the words "you can" are omitted from the second phrase.

This appears to be just wordplay, using the rhyme of theme and scheme. It doesn't really make much sense as prose. Typically we say "The story has a theme" or "The music has a theme", but we don't say "the person has a theme".

The writer probably meant something like "It was an idea that she had about a plan that he had." But to be honest this is an example of a grammatically correct but meaningless sentence.

Comment: There may be no [grammatical parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)), but that doesn't mean the lyric is devoid of [rhetorical parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(rhetoric)).